# image over div. Cant hover button below

Tags: html, css, image, hover

Im running into this problem. I have an image that NEEDS to be in this location over the divs. The leaf of the image needs to go over the div  but the image width goes too far and blocks other things in its way. In my case, it blocks the "contact us" button to be hovered. How can I fix this issue without moving the image from this set location. I have tried z-index but that does not work. I want to keep it the way it is, but with the ability to hover. Please help. I will attach an image and a FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/4jtzU/

[image]

HTML

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut l

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut l

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut l

Contact Us

```
<div id="boxes">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-container">
            <div class="box-img">
                <img src="http://www.nevsites.com/dish1.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn_test{
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    background: none;
    display:block;
    background-color: #FF8000;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: helevetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 70%;
    margin:10px auto;
    color:white;
   font-weight: bold;
    z-index:10;
   postion:relative;
}
.btn_test:hover{
   background-color: gray;
   cursor: pointer;
   display:block;
}
#mid-boxes-container{
   background: red;
   height:100px;
   width:100%;  
}
#mid-boxes{    
   width:80%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
.mid-box{
   padding: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   float:left;
   width:28%;
   height:150px;
   margin:0 .5%;
    color:white;
   background: red;
}
#boxes{
   margin:0 auto;
   margin-top: 50px;
   position: relative;
}
.box{
   width:100%;
   height: 600px;
   text-align: center;
   -webkit-animation: FadeIn 1s linear; 
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
   position: relative;
}

.box-container{
   margin: 10px;
   height: 100% ;
   position: relative;
}
.box-img{
   width:60%;
   position: relative;
   float:left;
}
.box-img img{
    width:1000px;
    position: relative;
   margin-top: -120px;
   margin-left: -340px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo on line 14 of the CSS, changing `postion:relative;` to `position:relative;` will correct the issue.

So it would end up looking like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4jtzU/3/

```
.btn_test{
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    background: none;
    display:block;
    background-color: #FF8000;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: helevetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 70%;
    margin:10px auto;
    color:white;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index:10;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle to show](http://jsfiddle.net/4jtzU/2/)

Your CSS had a typo on:

```
.btn-test {
    position:relative;
}
```

Oh and you don't need to re-state your `display: block` on the `.btn-test:hover` since you already did on its default state.